# DOM parsing an XML file - "Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence."

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, utf-8

I am trying to parse an xml file in the following way:

```
    System.out.println(path);
    File f = new File(path);        
    try {
        document = builder.parse(f);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`f` is the path to a `.xml` file with the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

As I understand it, that means that it has UTF-8 encoding. But this error only occurs if it does not have UTF-8 encoding. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error means that your builder is _assuming_ UTF-8, but the actual file is not UTF-8.

Comment: How can I tell what encoding it is using?

Comment: There is no perfect way to find out. Look at the hex dump, try some tools, intuit what it could be... It could be a simple thing like a completely garbled file.

Comment: Any recommendations for tools?

Comment: Google should help you there. I haven't got much experience with them. There is a Linux command.

Comment: From what I can tell from the hex dump, it's UTF-8. Any idea what else it might be (it starts with 3c 3f 78 6d), or why my program might not be seeing it as UTF-8?

Comment: Per [Section 4.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#TextEntities) and [Appendix F](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-guessing) of the XML spec, looking at the first few bytes of the file is enough to determine the encoding of the document's prolog so its `encoding` attribute can be read, if present. That tells the encoding of the rest of the document. If no `encoding` is present, UTF-8 *MUST* be assumed, unless a BOM or other external declaration (HTTP, etc) states otherwise...

Comment: ... In this situation, reading a standalone file, with no BOM or `encoding` present, UTF-8 has to be assumed, but the file contains a byte that is < `#xFF` (which is a 1-byte character sequence in UTF-8) that represents a Unicode character that is illegal in XML per [Section 2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) of the XML spec (`#x0` - `#x8`, `#xB` - `#xC`, or `#xE` - `#x19`), thus the error is reported.

Comment: Can you provide the actual XML file? Then someone can tell you what is wrong with it.